# How can I find the last row with a cell containing data vba to set print area?

Tags: vba, excel

I know this question may seem nearly identical to past ones, but there's a nuance in my sheet in that one of my columns is completely empty aside from the first 7 rows. The problem being that my code finds the last row in which **ALL** cells contain data rather than the last row with at least one data item. I.e. A1:Q7 contain data and since all of the rows contain data my code sets the print area to A1:Q7 although there is data in C14. I want my print area to be A1:Q14. How would I go about doing this. Code below.

```
Sub SetPrintArea()

Dim ALastFundRow As Integer
Dim AFirstBlankRow As Integer
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rngSheet As Range

Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WIRE SCHEDULE")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WIRE SCHEDULE")

'Finds last row of content
ALastFundRow = wksSource.Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row
 'Finds first row without content
AFirstBlankRow = ALastFundRow + 1

Set rngSheet = ws.Range("A1:Q" & LastFundRow + 7)

'Sets PrintArea to the last Column with a value and the last row with a value
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = rngSheet.Address
```

End Sub

Anything would help. Thanks!

Comment: FYI you're using just `LastFundRow` instead of `ALastFundRow` in the `Set rngSheet`.  Also, what's the difference in `wksSource` and `ws`? Finally, you could just use column C as the column in `ALastFundRow`, no? Or will it not always be C with the most data?

Comment: Oh whoops. Didn't mess with the function so I didn't notice. I'm very new to this so thanks for the tips and I tried but it didn't do anything :(

Comment: Are there gaps in column C? Try `ALastFundRow = wksSource.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function **GetLastCell()** will find the last row and column containing data

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SetPrintArea()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WIRE SCHEDULE")

    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:" & GetLastCell(ws).Address).Address

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function GetLastCell(Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet = Nothing) As Range
    Dim uRng As Range, uArr As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim ubR As Long, ubC As Long, lRow As Long

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set uRng = ws.UsedRange:    uArr = uRng
    If IsEmpty(uArr) Then
        Set GetLastCell = ws.Cells(1, 1):   Exit Function
    End If
    If Not IsArray(uArr) Then
        Set GetLastCell = ws.Cells(uRng.Row, uRng.Column):  Exit Function
    End If
    ubR = UBound(uArr, 1):      ubC = UBound(uArr, 2)
    For r = ubR To 1 Step -1    '----------------------------------------------- last row
        For c = ubC To 1 Step -1
            If Not IsError(uArr(r, c)) Then
                If Len(Trim$(uArr(r, c))) > 0 Then
                    lRow = r:   Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If lRow > 0 Then Exit For
    Next
    If lRow = 0 Then lRow = ubR
    For c = ubC To 1 Step -1    '----------------------------------------------- last col
        For r = lRow To 1 Step -1
            If Not IsError(uArr(r, c)) Then
                If Len(Trim$(uArr(r, c))) > 0 Then
                    Set GetLastCell = ws.Cells(lRow + uRng.Row - 1, c + uRng.Column - 1)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

---

[image: UR]

Answer (score 0):

```
 With ActiveSheet 'or whatever worksheet  
 LastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With
```

You can use a similar algorithm for the last column.

```
LastCol = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
```

Note that we are looking for `xlValues` so cells with formulas that return a null string will not be included.

If the worksheet is empty, the code will produce an error; so if that might be a possibility, you should test for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

**.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row**

```
Sub SetPrintArea()

Dim ALastFundRow As Integer
Dim AFirstBlankRow As Integer
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rngSheet As Range

Set wksSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WIRE SCHEDULE")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WIRE SCHEDULE")

'Finds last row of content
'ALastFundRow = wksSource.Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row
ALastFundRow = wksSource.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 'Finds first row without content
AFirstBlankRow = ALastFundRow + 1

Set rngSheet = ws.Range("A1:Q" & LastFundRow)

'Sets PrintArea to the last Column with a value and the last row with a value
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = rngSheet.Address
End Sub
```